# PDO login error, if ($this->data()->password === Hash::make($password, $this->data()->salt)) { always return error

Tags: php, authentication, pdo

I'm trying to create a PHP Login/Register system using PDO. The register part works just fine, however, when I try to login I always get an error telling me that the password is invalid even if it's the correct password.

I'll add a few scripts here and explain a little bit more underneath.

Register.php:

```
    <?php
    require_once 'core/init.php';

    $user = new User();
    if ($user->isLoggedIn()) {
        Redirect::to('index.php');
    }
    ?>

    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Register</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/global.css">
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="checkbox" id="toggle-left">
        <input type="checkbox" id="toggle-right">

        <div class="page-wrap">

            <?php require_once 'includes/header.php'; ?>
            <?php require_once 'includes/navbar.php'; ?>
            <?php require_once 'includes/profilebar.php'; ?>

            <div class="page-content">
                <form action="" method="post">
                    <h1>Register new account</h1>
                    <div class="inset">
                    <?php
                        if(Input::exists()) {
                            if (Token::check(Input::get('token'))) {

                                $validate = new Validate();
                                $validation = $validate->check($_POST, array(
                                    'username' => array(
                                        'required' => true,
                                        'min' => 3,
                                        'max' => 200,
                                        'first_not_numeric' => true,
                                        'unique' => 'users',
                                        'alias' => 'Username'
                                    ),
                                    'password' => array(
                                        'required' => true,
                                        'min' => 6,
                                        'alias' => 'Password'
                                    ),
                                    'password_again' => array(
                                        'alias' => 'Password confirmation', // <--- using the alias
                                        'required' => true,
                                        'matches' => 'password'
                                    ),
                                    'email' => array(
                                        'required' => true,
                                        'min' => 5,
                                        'max' => 200,
                                        'email' => true,
                                        'unique' => 'users',
                                        'alias' => 'Email'
                                    ),
                                    'first_name' => array(
                                        'max' => 100,
                                        'alias' => 'First name'
                                    ),
                                    'last_name' => array(
                                        'max' => 100,
                                        'alias' => 'Last name'
                                    ),
                                    'gender' => array(
                                        'required' => true,
                                        'alias' => 'Gender'
                                    )
                                ));

                                if ($validation->passed()) {
                                    $user = new User();

                                    $salt = Hash::salt(100);

                                    $k1 = hash('sha256', Input::get('email'));
                                    $k2 = hash('sha256', mt_rand(10000,99999).time().Input::get('email'));
                                    $k3 = hash('sha256', mt_rand(100000,999999).time().Input::get('username'));

                                    try {
                                        $user->create(array(
                                            'username' => Input::get('username'),
                                            'password' => Hash::make(Input::get('password'), $salt),
                                            'salt' => $salt,
                                            'email' => Input::get('email'),
                                            'email_code' => Input::get('email_code'),
                                            'k1' => $k1,
                                            'k2' => $k2,
                                            'k3' => $k3,
                                            'first_name' => Input::get('first_name'),
                                            'last_name' => Input::get('last_name'),
                                            'gender' => Input::get('gender'),
                                            'avatar' => $user->defaultProfilePic(),
                                            'joined' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                                            'group' => 1
                                        ));

                                        if (!file_exists("users/Input::get('username')")) {
                                            mkdir('users/'.Input::get('username'), 0755);
                                        }

                                        User::sendActivation(Input::get('email'), 'Email verification', 'Hello, '.Input::get('username').',
                                        <br>
                                        Please activate your account!<br>
                                        <a href="http://www.soldiersofwar.esy.es/activate.php?k1='.$k1.'&email_code='.Input::get('email_code').'&k2='.$k2.' &k3='.$k3.'">Click here to activate your account!</a>
                                        <br><br>
                                        Copy and paste this link if the one above doesn\'t work.<br>
                                        http://www.soldiersofwar.esy.es/activate.php?k1='.$k1.'&email_code='.Input::get('email_code').'&k2='.$k2.' &k3='.$k3.'
                                        <br>
                                        Thank you very much,<br>
                                        Soldiers Of War Staff');

                                        Session::flash('home', 'Please activate your account!');
                                        Redirect::to('index.php');

                                    } catch(Exception $e) {
                                        die($e->getMessage());
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    foreach ($validation->errors() as $error) {
                                        echo '<i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;', $error, '<br />';
                                        echo '<br />';
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ?>
                    <!-- Username -->
                    <div>
                        <label for="username">USERNAME</label>
                        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="<?php echo escape(Input::get('username')); ?>" required>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Password -->
                    <div>
                        <label for="password">ENTER A PASSWORD</label>
                        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" required>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Confirm Password -->
                    <div>
                        <label for="password_again">CONFIRM PASSWORD</label>
                        <input type="password" name="password_again" id="password_again" required>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Email Address -->
                    <div>
                        <label for="email">EMAIL ADDRESS</label>
                        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" value="<?php echo escape(Input::get('email')); ?>" required>
                    </div>

                    <!-- First Name -->
                    <div>
                        <label for="first_name">FIRST NAME</label>
                        <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" value="<?php echo escape(Input::get('first_name')); ?>">
                    </div>

                    <!-- Last Name -->
                    <div>
                        <label for="last_name">LAST NAME</label>
                        <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" value="<?php echo escape(Input::get('last_name')); ?>">
                    </div>

                    <!-- Gender -->
                    <div>
                        <label for="gender">GENDER</label>
                        <select class="gender" id="gender" name="gender" required>
                            <option value="">Select Gender:</option>
                            <option value="Male">Male</option>
                            <option value="Female">Female</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Token -->
                    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo Token::generate(); ?>">

                    <!-- Activation -->
                    <input type="hidden" name="email_code" value="<?php echo md5('username' + microtime()); ?>" />

                    <!-- Submit button -->
                    <p class="p-container">
                        <input type="submit" name="go" id="go" value="Register new account">
                    </p>
                </form>
            </div>
            <?php require_once 'includes/footer.php'; ?>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Login.php:

```
    <?php
    require_once 'core/init.php';

    $user = new User();
    if ($user->isLoggedIn()) {
        Redirect::to('index.php');
    }
    ?>

    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Log in</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/global.css">
        <script src="js/jQuery.js"></script>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>  
        <input type="checkbox" id="toggle-left">
        <input type="checkbox" id="toggle-right">

        <div class="page-wrap">

            <?php require_once 'includes/header.php'; ?>
            <?php require_once 'includes/navbar.php'; ?>
            <?php require_once 'includes/profilebar.php'; ?>

            <div class="page-content">
                <form action="" method="post">
                    <h1>Log in</h1>
                    <div class="inset">
                    <?php
                    if (Input::exists()) {
                        if (Token::check(Input::get('token'))) {

                            $validate = new Validate();
                            $validation = $validate->check($_POST, array(
                                'username' => array(
                                    'required' => true,
                                    'alias' => 'Username'
                                ),
                                'password' => array(
                                    'required' => true,
                                    'alias' => 'Password'
                                )
                            ));

                            if ($validation->passed()) {
                                $user = new User();

                                $remember = (Input::get('remember') === 'on') ? true : false;
                                $login = $user->login(Input::get('username'), Input::get('password'), $remember, $validate);

                                if ($login) {
                                    Redirect::to('index.php');
                                } else {
                                    foreach ($validation->errors() as $error) {
                                        echo '<i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;', $error, '<br>';
                                        echo '<br />';
                                        //echo '<pre>', print_r($validation->errors()), '</pre>';
                                    }
                                    /*$errors = $validate->errors();
                                    if(count($errors)>0){
                                         var_dump($errors);
                                    }*/
                                }

                            } else {
                                foreach ($validation->errors() as $error) {
                                    echo '<i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;', $error, '<br>';
                                    echo '<br />';
                                    //echo '<pre>', print_r($validation->errors()), '</pre>';
                                }
                                /*$errors = $validate->errors();
                                if(count($errors)>0){
                                     var_dump($errors);
                                }*/
                            } 

                        }
                    }

                    if(Session::exists('login')) {
                        echo '<p><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;' . Session::flash('login') . '</p><br />';
                    }
                    ?>
                    <p>
                        <label for="username">USERNAME</label>
                        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="<?php echo escape(Input::get('username')); ?>">
                    </p>
                        <!--<?php
                        /*if(isset($validation) && !$validation->passed()){
                            foreach($validation->errors() as $error){
                                if ($error->alias = 'Username') {
                                    echo '<i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;', $error, '<br>';
                                    echo '<br />';
                                }
                            }
                        }*/
                        ?>-->
                    <p>
                        <label for="password">PASSWORD</label>
                        <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember">
                        <label for="remember">Remember me for 1 month</label>
                    </p>
                    </div>

                    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo Token::generate(); ?>">
                    <p class="p-container">
                        <span>Forgot password?</span>
                        <span>Resend activation email</span>
                        <input type="submit" name="go" id="go" value="Log in">
                    </p>
                </form>
            </div>
            <?php require_once 'includes/footer.php'; ?>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Login function inside User class:

```
    public function login($username = null, $password = null, $remember = false, $validate = null) {

        if (!$username && !$password && $this->exists()) {
            Session::put($this->_sessionName, $this->data()->id);
        } else {
            $user = $this->find($username);
            if ($user) {
                if ($this->data()->password === Hash::make($password, $this->data()->salt)) {
                    if (1 === intval($this->data()->activated)) { 
                        Session::put($this->_sessionName, $this->data()->id);

                        if ($remember) {
                            $hash = Hash::unique();
                            $hashCheck = $this->_db->get('users_session', array('user_id', '=', $this->data()->id));

                            if (!$hashCheck->count()) {
                                $this->_db->insert('users_session', array(
                                    'user_id' => $this->data()->id,
                                    'hash' => $hash
                                ));
                            } else {
                                $hash = $hashCheck->first()->hash;
                            }

                            Cookie::put($this->_cookieName, $hash, Config::get('remember/cookie_expiry'));

                        }

                        return true;

                    } else {
                        $validate->addError('You need to activate your account before you login!');
                    }               

                } else {
                    $validate->addError('Invalid password!');
                }

            } else {
                $validate->addError('That username does not exist!');
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Hash class:

```
    <?php
    class Hash {
        public static function make($string, $salt = '') {
            return hash('sha512', $string . $salt);
        }

        public static function salt($length) {
            return mcrypt_create_iv($length);
        }

        public static function unique() {
            return self::make(uniqid());
        }
    }
```

So, now I'm going to explain in detail what the problem is.

When I register I use the Hash:: make() function to hash their password before storing it and a salt in the DB. When they try to login, in login.php, I call the login function inside the User class to make the login. And when the login function check if the details are correct, it takes the entered password and the salt in the db that's stored under the entered username, and hash it. Then it takes the hash stored in the db, and check if the new hash is the same as the stored one. If it is, the password is correct, otherwise it's not correct. But for some reason that I can't figure out, it always tells me that I enter an invalid password.

Everything worked in another project, but I can't get it working in this one for some reason, and I did compare the code in the old project with this one.

All help is appreciated, and if anyone need any info to be able to help, just let me know and I'll add it.

Thanks in advance,

Busarna

Comment: are you able to output `$this->data()->password` within the function? The condition where its failing is obviously `if ($this->data()->password === Hash::make($password, $this->data()->salt))` so output both to see if they match

Comment: Why not just use PHP's built-in `password_hash` `password_verify` functions?

Comment: When I output that I get the hash value in the db. But if I output the new hash it's not the same, however, when I output the salt or the entered password those are correct @zgr024

Comment: I didn't know that those existed when I started coding and I don't know how to use them well enough to know what to change in my code. @MikeBrant

Comment: @Busarna4 You may want to read up on the functions in the documentation.  There is not much sense in re-inventing the wheel if you are not really adding any value (in terms of security) along the way.  Those functions will actually simplify your design, eliminating the need for you to generate and store your salt separately (and in perhaps less secure fashion). You will also automatically be able to leverage any improvements in hashing methodology introduced in PHP in the future without having to make any code changes at all.

Comment: @Busarna4 I also just noticed you are providing a message back to user that user name does not exist.  This is usually not a good thing to do from a security standpoint, as a possible attacker can easily determine if they at least have one of the two items needed for login guessed correctly.  It is typically better to simply give a more generic "login failed" message.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the help. I'll change that, thanks for the tip. @MikeBrant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me give you an alternate example using `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` as I suggested in comments above.  I think you will see that this can simplify your design greatly.

First let's talk DB schema.  For this use case, you only need a single DB column related to saving the password hash. For this exercise, let's assume it is varchar(255), which is a good recommended column size.

To create the hash based on input password, code would look like this:

```
// I assume you have sanitized the password at this point
// and stored in this $password variable.
// You should also enforce password length limit of 72 characters.
$password = ...; 
$password_hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);    
if(false === $password_hash) {
   // something went wrong. log error
} else {
   // make your SQL insert to single password_hash field
   // note that the hash itself contains information on
   // the encryption methodology used and the salt
   // that was randomly generated to create the hash
}
```

For validating password, the code would look like this:

```
// I am assuming you have user input password
// you want to verify in variable $password_input
// and that you have already retrieved password hash
// from DB and have that stored in $password_hash
$password_input = ...;
$password_hash = ...;
$passwords_match = password_verify($password_input, $password_hash);
if (false === $passwords_match) {
    // password does not match. abort login        
} else {
    // password match. log user in
}
```

As you can see, the hash generation and hash verification take one line of code each.  It doesn't get simpler than that.

Answer (score 1):

From what you are saying, if the same code works in another project. I suggest you to check your database. Check the `hash` column length, you should set it large enough to fit the whole hash (they are usually very long).

When the column length is shorter than the actual value , the DB will store a truncated version of your hash thus the password check will always fail.

Comment: I thought about that as well but that's not it. The hash are around 130 chars but in the database I set it to 255 just to be safe. Also the salt is around 100 chars and I set it to 255 in the db there as well. Another reason that prove that that's not the answer is that not even the first char is the same, for example, one starts with 'cf' (without ' ') in the db but the new hash starts with '87' (without ' '). @meda Thanks in advance, Busarna

Comment: have you tried mike suggestion , do you neeed example of password_hash ?

Comment: No, I haven't tried that. If you got time to give me an example that would be great @meda